# Using grep to find specific information in a large file

Tags: command-line, grep

So I am doing some exercises to learn filtering large files using just the command line prompts. I have a large file called vehicles that has specific informations like license plate, car maker and its color. I am trying to filter out Blue Honda cars with a license plate that starts with L337. I am using grep command to do this. However I am struggling to use grep to filter multiple informations and putting them all together as an output.

This is what I got so far

```
grep -i -e "Honda" -e "blue" -e "L337" vehicles.txt -2
```

This is giving me different vehicles that either has Blue, Honda or L337 but I want to output vehicles that has all 3 of these variables. This is where I got stuck in.

Name of the file is vehicles.txt

This is an example of information it has on a vehicle

- License Plate: NVGRKG4
- Make : Honda
- Color: Yellow
- Owner : Captain Price

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: The "beauty" of the unix/linux command line is that you can chain most programs together to act as chains of  filters. `grep blue file | grep Honda | grep L337` . To see how much data you getting, you can append `| wc -l` to the end or, only do 2 `grep`s and a `wc` or even 1 `grep` and the `wc`. This isn't cheating, it's a feature (-;! Good luck.